# Prevent new row insert for each page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to tables and I am appending an json file to them.

```
<table id="userdata" border="2">
    <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>TotalUnresolvedItems</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<strong>Item2:</strong>
<table id="userdata2" border="2">
    <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>FullName</th>
    <th>TotalUnresolvedItems</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Every time setInterval triggers it adds new rows but i would like to remove exist rows and replace it with new one.
I have tried .remove() from different places but its removing forever :(
My code looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function () {
        refreshStatus();
        setInterval(refreshStatus, 30000);   
    });
    function refreshStatus() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "refreshTicketStatus",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                repopulateTable(data);
            },
            error: function (errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        })
    }
    function repopulateTable(data) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(parsedData);
        var dashboard = [];
        dashboard.push(JSON.parse(data));
        dashboard.forEach(function (value, index) {;
            for (var key in value) {
                if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    if (key === 'Item1') {
                        value[key].forEach(function (val) {
                            //$('#userdata tbody').remove(9000);
                            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + val.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.Title + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
                        })
                    }
                    if (key === 'Item2') {
                        value[key].forEach(function (val) {
                            //$('#userdata2 tbody').remove(9000);
                            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + val.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.FullName + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata2 tbody");
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: _I have tried .remove() from different places_ Where?  and What do you mean by _but its removing forever_?

Comment: Why not give the `<tr>` an ID, you could use `val.Id` assuming it's unique as ID's should be... that way you can target that row to be removed before appending it again or you could just target that row to be updated... I don't understand what you mean by *"its removing **forever**"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your repopulateDataTable function to the following. Basically I'm creating two empty variables, pass all the rows html in them and then replace all the html only once per interval.

```
function repopulateTable(data) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(parsedData);
    var dashboard = [];
    dashboard.push(JSON.parse(data));
    dashboard.forEach(function (value, index) {;
        var table1Rows  = "";
        var table2Rows  = "";
        for (var key in value) {
            if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (key === 'Item1') {
                    value[key].forEach(function (val) {
                        //$('#userdata tbody').remove(9000);
                        var tbl1Row = "<tr>" + "<td>" + val.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.Title + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                        table1Rows   += tbl1Row;
                    })
                }
                if (key === 'Item2') {
                    value[key].forEach(function (val) {
                        //$('#userdata2 tbody').remove(9000);
                        var tbl2Row = "<tr>" + "<td>" + val.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.FullName + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                        table2Rows   += tbl2Row;
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        $("#userdata tbody").html(table1Rows);
        $("#userdata2 tbody").html(table2Rows);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch. It solved my problem. I would like to accept your answer but i have less then 15 reputation. But i wont forget you :)

Comment: Hehe, no prob, glad to help!

Comment: @learning1216 for accepting answer no need to have more than 15 rep ,just click the "check" below the down vote button along with this answer.For upvote you need atleast 15 rep